# Clang is misinterpretting #import statement as a file, not a framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, clang, node-gyp

I have `#import <customframeworkname/customframeworkname.h>`. Xcode does list the frameworks under Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

However, when compiling it from the command line using Clang, it says:

```
../cppsrc/stuff.mm:6:9: fatal error: 'customframeworkname/customframeworkname.h' file not found
#import <customframeworkname/customframeworkname.h>
```

I tried changing it to the relative path by doing `#import <../customfwdir/customframeworkname/Headers/customframeworkname.h>`. Now it finds the file, but since a framework contains many headers, it doesn't recognize the framework's internal headers which uses `#import <customframeworkname/otherheader.h>`. Obviously, changing up the whole framework would be bad.

I'm super new to macOS development, any tips in the right direction would be appreciated!

Additional context: building a cross platform node.js addon, which is why I'm compiling it through commandline, specifically node-gyp. Node-gyp has a command to generate a xcode project file, which I use to check to make sure the build settings which I define in the bindings file do get properly translated to xcode settings.

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "myproj",
      "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
      "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
      "sources": [ 
        "cppsrc/wrapper.cc"
      ],
      "conditions": [
        ["OS=='mac'", {
          "xcode_settings": {
            "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS": "$(SRCROOT)/**"
          },
          "link_settings": {
            "libraries": [
              "customfws/fwname.framework"
            ]
          },
          "sources": [
            "cppsrc/stuff.mm"
          ]
        }]
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
      ],
      'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show the compile command you're using. Are you using `-F<path/to/framework/parent/dir>` and `-framework <customframeworkname>`?

Comment: I used to use -F and -framework, but that didn't work either. When i generated the Xcode project it wouldn't recognize them in Xcode either. Changing it to an absolute path seemed to make Xcode recognize it but it still didn't fix it.